# Allow multiple controllers to users according to their role in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-2.x

Suppose, there are two roles: one is `admin`, another is `restaurant_owner`.

I want to give access to some of the pages to `restaurant_owner`.

In `AppController`, I used `beforeFilter` function. Here is the code..

```
public function beforeFilter() {
   if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'restaurant_owner'){
     /* Controllers Name, that Admin want to give access to restaurant admin*/
      $this->loadModel('Userpermission');
      $AuthPermission = $this->Userpermission->find('first',array('conditions' => array('Userpermission.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
      print_r($AuthPermission); //returns controller names e.g. receipes, menuitems
  }
}
```

My question is, how I deny access to role `restaurant_owner` to all controllers except but a few? I'm using CakePHP 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of handling this is through [`ControllerAuthorize`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize) and the `AuthComponent::isAuthorized()` callback.

First, you have to enable this functionality in `AppController`. Edit your `Auth` config and array and add the following:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array('authorize' => 'Controller'),
);
```

Then add the following to the controllers which `restaurant_owner` should have access to:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {

    if ($user['role']=="restaurant_owner") {
        return true;
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Finally, add the following to `AppController`:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {

    if ($user['role']=="restaurant_owner") {
        return false;
    }

    return true; //Every other role is authorized
}
```

You will have to tweak the above logic to match your needs.